# function map in react

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

i'm a newbie in react and i have the following problem: i'm trying to get the objects from a get (axios) and play on the screen using the map, but i'm doing it wrong, if anyone can help me i would be grateful.

the requisition brought me the following items:

0: {username: "eqwe", name: "weqeqw", email: "eqwwqe", city: "qweewq", id: "fxm8j"}

1: {username: "sadsa", name: "asdads", email: "asdas", city: "sddsadsa", id: "79ywn"}

2: {username: "aaa", name: "aaa", email: "aaaa", city: "aaaaa", id: "8shpw"}

3: {username: "ddd", name: "ddd", email: "dddd", city: "ddd", id: "aourz"}

4: {username: "teste", name: "teste", email: "teste", address: {…}, city: "teste", …}
...

this is my code:

```
import {getUsers} from '../actions';


function Table(){

const [data, setData] = useState({data: []});

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(){
        const result = await getUsers();
        setData(result);
        console.log("teste: ", result);
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);
return(
     {data.map((item) => 
     <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>)}
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain if you have any error message or where do you see any issues? What is the structure for `result` variable on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make nested object in state.

```
import {getUsers} from '../actions';
function Table(){

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(){
        const result = await getUsers();
        setData(result);
        console.log("teste: ", result);
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);
return(
     {data.map((item) => 
     <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>)}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the `{ ... }`:

```
return data.map(item => (
   <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
));
```

`{ }` inside a component are used to insert the result of an expression. However, you are not inside an element (not inside `<tag> ... </tag>`) therefore `{ }` will just denote a block of code.